# How do I write the names of letters in a book?

Tags: description

I have a situation where I am trying to explain a company logo that is flashing in propaganda. Let us say the logo is an "M" overlaying a "Y," how would I write that?

I would think one would write, "The darkness was interrupted as light burst forth from the monitor on the wall. An ⟨M⟩ overlaying a ⟨Y⟩ appeared on screen as a voice chimed, 'Mart Yuth International; your friends, no hassle today.'"

I would think you would write that, but that does not look right; would I spell the names of the letters? there is really no standard for most of the names and if I write, "an im overlaying a wigh," well that's just unorthodox.

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to give a detailed description of the company logo in the first place? I take it you're writing something that's intended to be delivered *written*, not a movie script or similar (which would offer its own solutions to this). For me personally, I'd likely just find your second example ("an im overlaying a wigh") confusing rather than enlightening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use capital letters, "an M overlaying a Y", you may find that an editor and/or publisher has some specific punctuation that they prefer to use in this situation but in terms of conveying the information you don't *need* anything special.